# Does a plus sign indicate to login to access associated price

Tags: mobile, login, e-commerce

The aim is to get the customer to login. So we are providing a different pricing model when signed in, does a plus sign indicate to the customer to tap this (a pop up to login will appear) and then the user will have access to this new price.

(The quantity selector will allow you to change the amount of bottles so you don't have to get the case)

[image: Accessing Members Pricing]

Comment: No, it dose not! A "plus" sign indicates "ADDING"  something to something. In this case, it means simply "Add to basket".

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for the question.

What I understand is that you want user to be shown a different price when they login and you are trying to use + icon for user to login.

If that is the use case then the proposed solution doesnt suffice.

This shows that you are adding something to the cart. Either

1. You can still use any sign up icon to do that. or
2. You can use sign up in a prompt that you can use.

Please comment if I have got the understand correct else I will check it again.

Answer (score 0):

A plus sign on its own doesn't indicate that it might be connected with any kind of discount price or membership. In fact, it only suggests that pressing the button might add something - either adding the item to the basket or increasing the number of items the user wishes to add to the basket.

The only store I can think of that operates this kind of scheme where I am is "Go Outdoors" (gooutdoors.co.uk). Here's how they handle the problem:

I don't have a membership so it's going to show me the non-members view.

They start by showing the members' price strongly with the full price below in much smaller text - This is most likely to attract the user to buy while still maintaining a level of transparency about the non-member pricing:

[image]

There are no further mentions of the prices anywhere else on the page and the buy button simply says "Add to basket".

Once the user has added the item to the basket there are multiple attempts to encourage the user to either login or sign up to the membership scheme. The price priority also reflects their membership status - Members continue to see the members' prices all the way through to the sub-total while non-members' prices are marked as the full price with a smaller text showing the members' price.

One of the things we want to think about here is how far the user has to be invested in the buying process before we can interrupt their flow with a login/signup request without losing their business. A lot of companies do this by allowing the user to compile their basket and get all the way to the start of the checkout process before the interruption occurs. This way, the user has put time and effort into choosing the items that they want and they are more reluctant to just abandon the process.

My suggestion would be to look around for other members or club-based discount stores and figure out how they handle this problem. This will give you much more insight into how other designers have handled this task and which solutions are more effective.